# do contracts lock my out of funds?

Tags: contract-invocation

I copied the crowdsale contract from the ethereum website and now that ether is in in the time has expired and the goal is met how do i get the ether? I have already tried the safe withdrawal is goes through but I never get the funds back into my etherbase. What am I doing wrong?

Page I copied from: https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale

Comment: If funding goal was reached (fundingGoalReached is true) only the beneficiary can retrieve the total balance of the contract using safeWithdrawal (the beneficiary was declared when the contract was deployed and cannot be changed). In the other case when fundingGoalReached is false, each contributor can retrieve its deposit.

Comment: This is the address 0x44E8173818a6fA6F36F2D5C385aA852703CB51b4

Comment: The funding goal is not met and I am also the main beneficiary to the account. I think I should take each contributor getting the deposit back path since I am the only one who contributed. How can I take the path?

Comment: From https://etherscan.io/address/0x44E8173818a6fA6F36F2D5C385aA852703CB51b4 the only transactions to that contratc are from 0x3bc829f00b84891b0147b77d6170827f9d8c30fd, if you control this address you can call safeWithdrawal, and it will return your deposit.

Comment: Okay I tried that and it looks like it is trying to send fund from 0x3bc829f00b84891b0147b77d6170827f9d8c30fd to the crowdfund contract when i execute safe withdrawal. Backwards of what I want...

Comment: I've verified the code in etherscan with the compiler solc v0.4.7+commit.822622cf. I'd suggest to first call `checkGoalReached` and then `safeWithdrawal` from the address 0x3bc829f00b84891b0147b77d6170827f9d8c30fd. If you call `balanceOf` for that address it will return a non zero value, that you should be able to retrieve.

Comment: Okay once I am update I will run the checkgoalreached function first and then run the safewithdrawal. Where will the checkgoalreached info be displayed?

Comment: I see there's an internal transaction 0x100e1ede59a9a1a4fd2d4448b4a1f49963e4e77b8ae5ba7882ed85b42c60303d (Jul-08-2017 02:45:15 AM +UTC), done from that address but it is done through a multisig wallet. That will not work it has to be directly from 0x3bc829f0... address or else it will not work.

Comment: What wallet can I use that will work or how can I do this properly. I have ethereum wallet and mist wallet but my contracts only show up in mist.

Comment: That was probably my smart wallet account I will try to do it through my etherbase which is the main address but I think I tried that and it did not work. I will let you know after trying all the suggestions.

Comment: Both Ethereum Wallet and MyEtherWallet should work, just make sure the call is from is 0x3bc829f0...

Comment: Okay thanks I will try that as soon as I am resynced and give you an update. Thanks a million for the help once again.